# I am having trouble activating my unity license and getting unity hub up and running

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation

I'm trying to set up unity hub but I got a license and every time I try to use it tells me to refresh or return my license so I do and then I try to I'm told to active with a serial number license request or get a free personal license.

I tried all 3 choices, but they got me the same type of license that only says my activation date and to refresh my license.

Comment: In the settings on Unity Hub, is your license active? You could try using another email to get a new license unless you've paid for a license in which case there's a bigger problem.

Comment: Sounds like you have an internet proxy server. Mine doesn’t work when behind one either